# How to change CreatedBy in work item history?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I am trying to change the CreatedBy field in a work item to a test user I have. The CreatedBy field is being updated on the creation of the work item and I have bypassRules set to true. For a bit I thought the code I wrote was not updating the CreatedBy field because in the History section it still said: "USER created the User Story". Note that "USER" is the member who has the access token.
However, if I pull the work item I just created and pull the CreatedBy information it points out to the test user member, which is correct behavior. So my only problem is that history is not updating, is there a way to change CreatedBy in the history section? Below is a snippet of the code I am using to create the work item.

```
patchDocument.Add(
        new JsonPatchOperation()
        {
                Operation = Operation.Add,
                Path = "/fields/System.CreatedBy",
                Value = workItem.CreatedBy        //Represents string "Test User"
                    
         }
);

WorkItem result = workItemTrackingHttpClient.CreateWorkItemAsync(patchDocument, project, "User Story", bypassRules: true).Result;

Console.WriteLine("User Story Successfully Created: User Story #{0}", result.Id);

workItem.ItemId = (int)result.Id;

WorkItem testResult = workItemTrackingHttpClient.GetWorkItemAsync(project, workItem.ItemId).Result;

IdentityRef createdBy = (IdentityRef)testResult.Fields["System.CreatedBy"];
Console.WriteLine(createdBy.DisplayName);  //This correctly displays "Test User"
                
return result;
```

Comment: To my knowledge, work item history is immutable. For organizations subject to audit, it would be difficult to convince an auditor that history is legitimate if it can be altered.

Comment: @WaitingForGuacamole I see, makes sense. I figured it could be changed since it would be altered during creation. Guess I'll have to do without it. Appreciate the help!

Comment: Yeah, that's a tricky one. Microsoft also has to be able to support tickets that ask, "What happened to my work item? The history says X, but I KNOW that didn't happen". Now, if changing the history record also created a history record saying a history record had changed, well...

Comment: Yeah, that would solve that problem.